# Why can Rust not infer the proper lifetime in simple closures, or infers they are conflicting?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have not found any rules in the Rust documentation that would explain how lifetime elision applies to closures. Let's take a simple example:

```
fn foo(s: &str) {
    let id = |x: &str| x;
    println!("{}", id(s));
}

fn main() {
    foo("string");
}
```

I thought that the closure in the `foo` function would work similar to the following code:

```
fn foo(s: &str) {
    struct Id;  // A helper structure for closure
    impl Id {
        fn id(self: Self, x: &str) -> &str { &x }
    }
    let id = Id; // Creating a closure
    println!("{}", id.id(s));
}
```

The latter works fine, but the former fails to compile and produces a long error message about conflicting lifetime requirements:

```
t3.rs:2:24: 2:25 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements [E0495]
t3.rs:2     let id = |x: &str| x;
                               ^
t3.rs:2:24: 2:25 note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 2:23...
t3.rs:2     let id = |x: &str| x;
                               ^
t3.rs:2:24: 2:25 note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected `&str`, found `&str`)
t3.rs:2     let id = |x: &str| x;
                               ^
<std macros>:3:11: 3:36 note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the expression at 3:10...
<std macros>:3 print ! ( concat ! ( $ fmt , "\n" ) , $ ( $ arg ) * ) ) ;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<std macros>:2:25: 2:56 note: in this expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:3:1: 3:54 note: in this expansion of print! (defined in <std macros>)
t3.rs:3:5: 3:27 note: in this expansion of println! (defined in <std macros>)
<std macros>:3:11: 3:36 note: ...so type `(&&str,)` of expression is valid during the expression
<std macros>:3 print ! ( concat ! ( $ fmt , "\n" ) , $ ( $ arg ) * ) ) ;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<std macros>:2:25: 2:56 note: in this expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:3:1: 3:54 note: in this expansion of print! (defined in <std macros>)
t3.rs:3:5: 3:27 note: in this expansion of println! (defined in <std macros>)
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I wonder why Rust cannot infer the proper lifetime in simple closures like the one that I wrote above. Moreover, why does the compiler think that there are *conflicting* requirements for lifetime.

Comment: Remove the `: &str` and it works. The `&str` there doesn’t mean what you think it means. I have no time to explain now, however, as I should be in bed.

Comment: Actually, I meant '&str', because it is necessary in a bit more complex case. In any case, my question was not how to get this trivial example to work, but what are the rules here? Why does the compiler finds the conflicting requirements here?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: If you have some time, it would be great if you could explain what's going on. I have a feeling it could be due to an inferred `for<'a>` but it's not quite clear... and the lack of answer after 20 hours seems to mean I am not the only one unsure of what's going on ^^

Answer (score 3):

When you specify the type of a parameter or the return type in a closure, and that type is a reference, the compiler sets wrong expectations on the implicit lifetime parameter, and there's no way to define the lifetime parameter explicitly on a closure. [This is a known issue.](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22340) The workaround is to omit the parameter's type or the return type and let the compiler infer everything.

```
fn foo(s: &str) {
    let id = |x| x;
    println!("{}", id(s));
}

fn main() {
    foo("string");
}
```

If you still need to give a type hint, you can do so with a `let` binding inside the closure:

```
fn foo(s: &str) {
    let id = |x| { let y: &str = x; y };
    println!("{}", id(s));
}

fn main() {
    foo("string");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closure can't infer the lifetime from the method signature. Effectively you're defining a lifetime in the method signature let's say it's implicitly `'a`, and another lifetime, implicitly `'b` in the closure.

Match up the lifetimes and it will compile.

```
fn foo<'a>(s: &'a str) {
    let id = |x: &'a str| x;
    println!("{}", id(s))
}

fn main() {
    foo("string");
}
```

Comment: I am sorry if I worded my question badly, but I was interested in the _rules_ for lifetime inference in closures, not how to get the code to compile. Also I tried a version with a static string: `id("string")`, and Rust still cannot infer the lifetime correctly and produce the same error. If Rust does not support lifetime inference in closures, I have no problem to specify it explicitly, but the error message said about _conflicting_requirements_, which I find very confusing.